# PyCharm Terminal has different Python than Mac Terminal

Tags: python, pycharm

Running the below.

PyCharm shows:

```
% python -V
Python 2.7.16

% where python
bash: where: command not found
```

whereas in Terminal it shows:

```
% python -V
Python 3.8.12

% where python
/Users/ryo/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

**Why is the PyCharm terminal using a different version of Python compared to my iOS Terminal?** Any direction would be appreciated - I've Googled this extensively and searched through StackOverflow but this apparently simple problem is beyond me.

Not sure if it has anything to do with my `PATH` variable but pasted below for reference:

Mac Terminal

```
$PATH
/Users/ryo/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ryo/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

[image: Terminal Shell Path]

The interpreter looks like this.

[image]

Comment: If you have a virtual environment set up in your PyCharm project, the PyCharm terminal will automatically activate it.  That could give you a different version of Python.

Comment: Thank you - creating a new virtual environment fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm as a convenience will set your terminal python to the project interpreter you have in your settings.  You can change it by going to Settings -> Project: <project name> -> Python Interpreter

Comment: The Python interpreter I have selected (3.10) does not match either the Mac Terminal nor the Pycharm Terminal.